# Paypal with delphi using REST API Return Payment Empty

Tags: delphi, rest, paypal, indy

i try to make a delphi application using paypal REST API.

First the TOKEN and is working fine:

```
var
  slParameters:TStringList;
  Response:TStringStream;
  json, sTokenType:string;
  PayPalObj:TJSONObject;
  jTokenValue:TJSONValue;
begin
memLog.Lines.Clear;
memLog.Lines.Add('TOKEN');
btnPayment.Enabled := False;
http.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
http.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
http.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en_US';
http.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
http.Request.Username := 'AQXYqhB1xxHcxHIg2grwyWny6VcGSJsvlMI4v1vNEPrTzbhZc4bHVEJXmvgX';
http.Request.Password := 'EE9wTBCqyKWWRRLU5otmzvE407va_NitLwnegxKwtt_D9RmmXbh7_kePLN3I';

slParameters := TStringList.Create;
Response := TStringStream.Create;
try
  //get an access token
  slParameters.Add('grant_type=client_credentials');
  json := http.Post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', slParameters);
  //json := Response.DataString;
  PayPalObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json), 0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    jTokenValue := PayPalObj.Get('access_token').JsonValue;
    AccessToken := jTokenValue.Value;
    jTokenValue := PayPalObj.Get('token_type').JsonValue;
    sTokenType := jTokenValue.Value;

    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Text := PayPalObj.ToString;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Size: ' + IntToStr(PayPalObj.EstimatedByteSize));
  finally
    PayPalObj.Free;
  end;

  if sTokenType <> 'Bearer' then
    Exit;

  if AccessToken = '' then
    Exit;

  lblToken.Caption := Format('Token: %s - Type: %s', [AccessToken, sTokenType]);
  btnPayment.Enabled := True;
finally
  Response.Free;
  slParameters.Free;
end;end;

procedure TfrmPayPalREST.httpAuthorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
memLog.Lines.Add('*** Authorization ***');
memLog.Lines.Add(Authentication.ToString);
memLog.Lines.Add(' ');
```

But on the payment, always returns a empty json response

```
var
  PayPalObj :TJSONObject;
  PayPalObj2 :TJSONObject;
  RedirectObj :TJSONObject;
  PayerObj :TJSONObject;

  TransactionsArray : TJSONArray;
  AmountObj : TJSONObject;
  TransactionObj : TJSONObject;
  FundingArray : TJSONArray;
  CreditCardObj : TJSONObject;

  ssJson : TStringStream;
  json, Authorization:string;
begin
//create a payment
memLog.Lines.Add('PAYMENT');
PayPalObj := TJSONObject.Create;
try
  RedirectObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    RedirectObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('return_url', TJSONString.Create('http://blahblah.com/return')));
    RedirectObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('cancel_url', TJSONString.Create('http://blahblah.com/cancel')));
  except
    RedirectObj.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  PayerObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    PayerObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('payment_method', TJSONString.Create('credit_card')));

    CreditCardObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('number', '5500005555555559');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('type', 'mastercard');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('expire_month', '12');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('expire_year', '2018');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('cvv2', '111');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('first_name', 'yo');
    CreditCardObj.AddPair('last_name', 'tu');

    FundingArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    FundingArray.Add(CreditCardObj);

    PayerObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('funding_instruments', FundingArray));
  except
    PayerObj.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  TransactionsArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  AmountObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  TransactionObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    AmountObj.AddPair('currency', TJSONString.Create('USD'));
    AmountObj.AddPair('total', TJSONString.Create('1'));
    TransactionObj.AddPair('amount', AmountObj);
    TransactionObj.AddPair('description', TJSONString.Create('payment description'));
    TransactionsArray.Add(TransactionObj);
  except
    TransactionsArray.Free;
    AmountObj.Free;
    TransactionObj.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  PayPalObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('intent', TJSONString.Create('sale')));
  PayPalObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('payer', PayerObj));
  PayPalObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('transactions', TransactionsArray));
  //PayPalObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('redirect_urls', RedirectObj));

  Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PayPalObj.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Size: ' + IntToStr(PayPalObj.EstimatedByteSize));

  http.Request.Clear;
  http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  //http.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;  //have tried this with no success
  Authorization := Format('Bearer %s', [AccessToken]);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', Authorization);  //token obtained from first request

  Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(http.Request.CustomHeaders.Text);
  ssJson := TStringStream.Create(PayPalObj.ToString, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    json := http.Post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment', ssJson);
    lblPayment.Caption := json;

    PayPalObj2 := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json), 0) as TJSONObject;
    if Assigned(PayPalObj2) then
      try
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
        Memo1.Lines.Add(PayPalObj2.ToString);
      finally
        PayPalObj2.Free;
      end;
  finally
    ssJson.Free;
  end;
finally
  PayPalObj.Free;
end;
```

Any One know why? Thank you for the help

Using Delphi XE6 with Indy, this is a android app by the way

[Delphi Source Code](http://www.itcmx.com/PayPalREST.rar)

PS: i use the follow question: 
[Using PayPal REST client with Delphi XE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395669/using-paypal-rest-client-with-delphi-xe2/26436321#26436321) but there is not any answer there

Comment: Did you validate that your input JSON is correct to begin with?  Did you try contacting PayPal for assistance? Your are using someone else's code from another question, without any indication as to whether you made any changes to it, or what the actual response data looks like.

Comment: Hi, i compare with the code on developer.paypal.com and have the same format.
I copied the same json of this page and I get the same result, a blank json.
I am using curl: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/curl?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

On the developer.paypal.com has this forum to get help, else a set a message on the suppor page. With the same data and demo.

And the other question is inactive and has no other answers, thank you for you reply

Comment: Define *blank json* exactly. What does the full response actually look like?

Comment: Hi,

Like this JSON = ''

Y Check and the ResponseCode is 401, i think the problem is in the follow lines:

  Authorization := Format('Bearer %s', [AccessToken]);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', Authorization);  //token obtained from first request

Where AccessToken is obtained on the firs function and save on a Private Field of the form.

Comment: ResponseCode 401 is the server asking for authorization. What does the entire response look like? In particular, the `WWW-Authenticate` header(s). Are the `OnSelectAuthorization` and `OnAuthorization` events being triggered? Also, try using `CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Authorization` instead of `CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', Authorization)`, and make sure that `Request.BasicAuthentication` is false.

Comment: Using the code for step1, i only get a HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request... Any hints ?